# algebra and discrete mathematics prove

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve this question but it's bit confusing.
Can someone please help me with this question?

(a) Prove the following either by direct proof or by contraposition:
Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $a \equiv 1 (mod \ 5)$, then $a^2 \equiv 1 (mod \ 5)$.

(b) Prove the following by contradiction:
Suppose $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $4|(a^2 + b^2$), then $a$ and $b$ are not both odd.

(c) Disprove the following by counterexamples:
• For every natural number $n$, the integer $n^2 + 17n + 17$ is prime.
• Let $A, B$ and $C$ be sets. If $A × C = B × C$, then $A = B$.

(d) Prove the following by cases: $\forall n \in  \mathbb{Z}$, $n^2 + 3n + 4$ is even.

(e) Prove the following by induction:
$1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + · · · + (2n − 1)^2 = \frac{n}{3}\times(2n − 1)(2n + 1)$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiDEb.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You will get better results if you (a) put some effort into typesetting the question; (b) put some effort into solving the question, and share what you've tried; (c) put some effort into clarifying which parts of the question you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

$a)$ For $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $a\equiv \pmod 5\Rightarrow a=5k+1$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Squaring both sides we get,

$a^2=25k^2+10k+1=5(5k^2+2k)+1=5m+1$, where $m=5k^2+2k$ and $\in \mathbb{Z}$

So, $a^2 \equiv 1\pmod 5$

---

$b)$ For the sake of contradiction let $a,b$ both be odd.

Let $a=2m+1$ and $b=2n+1$, where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\therefore$ $a^2=4m^2+4m+1$ and $b=4n^2+4n+1$

$a^2+b^2=4(m^2+n^2+m+n)+2=4k+2$, where $k=m^2+n^2+m+n$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now, if $4 \mid a^2+b^2 \Rightarrow 4 \mid 4k+2 \Rightarrow 4 \mid 2$ (*Contradiction*)

Thus, $a,b$ can't both be odd numbers.

---

$c)$

$1)$ $n=16,17$ is a immediate counterexample to the primality of the integer $m(n)=n^2+17n+17$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

- For $n=16$, $m(16)=16^2+17 \cdot 16 +16=16 \cdot (16+1) +17\cdot 16=2 \cdot 17 \cdot 16$
- For $n=17$, $m(17)=17^2+17 \cdot 17+17$.

It may be seen $17 \mid m(n)$, for $n=16,17$

$2)$ Set $C=\phi$, and then it would be seen that $A$ may or may not be equal to $B$

---

$e)$

Let $P(n): 1^2+3^2+\ldots (2n-1)^2=\dfrac{n(2n-1)(2n+1)}{3}$

*Base Case:*

$P(1): 1^2=1=\dfrac{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 3}{3}$

So, $P(1)$ is true.

*Inductive Hypothesis:*

$P(k)$ is true.

$\therefore 1^2+3^2+\ldots (2k-1)^2=\dfrac{k(2k-1)(2k+1)}{3}$

*Inductive Step:*

$P(k+1): [1^2+3^2+\ldots (2k-1)^2]+ (2k+1)^2$

Using the *Inductive Hypothesis*, we have $P(k+1): \dfrac{k(2k-1)(2k+1)}{3}+(2k+1)^2=(2k+1) \cdot \dfrac{k(2k-1)+3(2k+1)}{3}=\dfrac{(k+1)(2k+1)(2k+3)}{3}$

$\therefore P(k+1)$ is true.

So, by principal of mathematical induction $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

For d):

Notice that $ n^2+3n=n(n+3) \  \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $n$ is even, then $(n+3)$ is odd (using the parity rule $even\pm odd = odd$) and then use the rule $even \times odd = even$ to get that if $n$ is even, $n(n+3)$ is even.

If $n$ is odd, then $(n+3)$ is even (using the rule $odd\pm odd = even$) and then use the rule $odd \times even= even$ to get that if $n$ is odd, then $n(n+3)$ is even.

So $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \ n(n+3)$ is even.

Finally, use the rule $even \pm even= even$ to get the desired result.

Obviously I used some parity results, so if you need to be rigorous you may consider other proofs or maybe prove the parity rules used in this one.